# How can I use class-validator to check if a number is above or below?

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I'm trying to check if a number is between 0 and 100. So I did this:

```
@Min(0.0000000000001)
@Max(99.9999999999999)
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I compare number variables with 'class-validator'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980341/can-i-compare-number-variables-with-class-validator)

Comment: yes that's helpful, but not directly. I have added an answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationOptions } from 'class-validator'

export function IsGreaterThan(threshold: number, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: object, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            name: 'isGreaterThan',
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            constraints: [threshold],
            options: validationOptions,
            validator: {
                validate(value: any) {
                    return typeof value === 'number' && value > threshold
                },
            },
        })
    }
}

export function IsSmallerThan(threshold: number, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: object, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            name: 'isSmallerThan',
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            constraints: [threshold],
            options: validationOptions,
            validator: {
                validate(value: any) {
                    return typeof value === 'number' && value < threshold
                },
            },
        })
    }
}
```